# How to create .audit file to upload a custom amazon AWS audit for Audit Cloud Infrastructure

Tags: nessus

I am new to nessus Audit Cloud Infrastructure. I have an infrastructure over AWS cloud with Unix based machine.
Audit Cloud Infrastructure requires an audit file without it an error is coming as below :-

> Error (400): At least one audit must be added to this policy in the
>   'Compliance' section.

I have tried to search a sample .audit file which I can import for my policy but I haven't get anything.

As per the slide below, there is tool as i2a but I haven't able to get that and neither I am able to contact with support portal(may be because I am using the trial version for now) :-

https://www.slideshare.net/jderienzo/create-a-nessus-audit-file-30230893

If anyone have any source of .audit file please share it. specially for unix one. Or please atleast provide some link/video etc so I can create my own .audit file.

I have tried below link but it didn't work for me:-

https://www.tenable.com/blog/version-2-of-windows-compliance-checks-available-for-testing

[image]

Any help is appreciated in advance!!

Comment: I have added "CIS Amazon Web Services Foundations Audit " and it worked for me but don't know how .audit file will help to extract the real issues of AWS. Any suggestion will be welcome